# Creating API using Flask-Restless and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, api, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on an API and I don't seem to get the syntax right. What I want to do is have a nested three level API of the 1 to many relationships. 
A farm has multiple families, each family has multiple persons, but each person only has one family and each family only lived at one farm.

What I have is this:

```
class farm(db.Model):
    farm_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    area_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('area.area_id'))
    farm_name = Column(Text, unique=False)
    families = relationship('family_id',primaryjoin="farm.farm_id==family.farm_id")


class family(db.Model):
    family_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    farm_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('farm_id.farm_id'))
    person = relationship('person_id',primaryjoin="family.family_id==person.family_id")


class person(db.Model):
    person_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    family_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('family.family_id'))
    family_data = Column(Text, unique=False)
    family_year = Column(Text, unique=False)
```

This gives me two API:s, both being two levels. What I want to do is join them so that I only need one three-level API. But I can't figure it out. What the API looks like from the code above is like this:

```
farm object:
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "area_id": 1,
      "families": [
        {
          "family_id": 1,
          "farm_id": 1
        }
      ],
      "farm_id": 1,
      "farm_name": "farm_one"
    },
```

And the family object:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "family_id": 1,
      "farm_id": 1,
      "persons": [
        {
          "family_data": "Name",
          "family_id": 1,
          "family_year": "Date",
          "person_id": 1
        }
      ]
    },
```

What I would like to get is below, but no matter what I try to join and relationship declare the data, it doesn't give me this:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "area_id": 1,
      "families": [
        {
          "family_id": 1,
          "farm_id": 1,
          "persons": [
            {
              "family_data": "Name",
              "family_year": "Date",
              "person_id": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "farm_id": 1,
      "farm_name": "farm_one"
    },
```

Do you guys have any idea about what I'm missing here?

Comment: You're missing a reference from `Family` to `Person`. Look for `backreference`, `back_populates`.

Comment: That doubles the person object, but does not deepen the three, which is what I was looking to do.